# Quick ways to manipulate Numpy array in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to find a way to quickly manipulate an array of arrays in Numpy like this one, which has a shape of (10,):

```
[array([0, 1, 3]) ,array([0, 1, 7]), array([2]), array([0, 3]), array([4]),
 array([5]), array([6]) ,array([1, 7]), array([8]), array([9])]
```

For instance, I'd like to compute the total number of array elements, which is 16 for the array above, but without doing a for loop since in practice my "nested array" will be quite large.

Thanks!

Comment: Define "manipulation". If all you want is the length, it would be better to flatten into a single array. Otherwise your only choice s iteration because these arrays are uneven length.

Comment: That's a list of arrays - or object dtype array.  Loops, list comprehensions are the normal tools.  `np.frompyfunc` may be useful in some cases, with a modest speed difference.

Comment: As shown in the answer, 'flattening' the list into one array with concatenate way help.  It depends on the manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

One way to find the length of the array in your case is to **ravel** the nested numpy arrays and then find the length as below:

```
a = [array([0, 1, 3]) ,array([0, 1, 7]), array([2]), array([0, 3]), array([4]),
 array([5]), array([6]) ,array([1, 7]), array([8]), array([9])]

len(np.concatenate(a).ravel())
#Here we expand the numpy arrays and then flatten it to find the length.
```

Output:

```
16
```

As per my knowledge, ravel has a better timeit performance time in comparison to for loop.

Comment: I don't think you need the ravel here.